# Я пытался установить AirDoS на андроид, но по каким-то причинам у меня ошибка

Tags: android, termux

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/AirDoS/AirDoS.py", line 17, in 
from opendrop.client import AirDropBrowser, AirDropClient
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opendrop/client.py", line 32, in 
from .util import AirDropUtil, AbsArchiveWrite
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/opendrop/util.py", line 29, in 
from libarchive import ffi
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libarchive/ffi.py", line 26, in 
libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/**init**.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/**init**.py", line 374, in **init**
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen failed: library "/usr/local/opt/libarchive/lib/libarchive.dylib" not found

Comment: `.dylib` это для macOS, что-то вы там не то творите либо вопрос неверно сформулирован.

Comment: Я знаю, что это для мака. Моя цель запустить это на андроид.

Comment: А как можно бинарники от мака запустить на линуксе?